# python не ставятся модули numpy и pandas

Tags: python, pandas

"Раньше всё работало".
Переставил Python (был 3.8.7)
win 32 bit
Пробовал версии 3.8.7 / 3.10.11 / 3.11.3
Ставлю модуль Pandas:

`python -m pip install pandas`

Сообщает, что успешно установлено.
Запускаю в IDLE:

`import pandas as pd`

или

`import numpy as np`

ответом:

`= RESTART: Shell =`

То есть если запустить программу с этой строкой, то она просто молча без ошибок закрывается.

А другие модули которые ставятся вместе с пандой нормально грузятся:

`import tzdata`

`import six`

Помогите, пожалуйста! )
Проверил на другом компе win 32 bit, на котором раньше и Питона не ставилось, такая же унылая картина..